# How do I get my etch-a-sketch program to "listen" to this dropdown menu instead of the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Stack Overflow. I hope that I'm doing this correctly. ❤

I'm working on an old Etch-a-Sketch JavaScript project from months ago and decided to rework the 'mobile' form of the project because I hadn't bothered to do so at the time. At first, I tried just moving the buttons to the top horizontally, but I didn't like any of the variations I tried. So I decided I'd be better off with a dropdown menu instead that would appear when the screen is 500px or smaller, replacing the buttons.

The dropdown menu is supposed to do exactly what the buttons do - when a certain mode is selected, that's the mode that the program is supposed to switch to. For example, when the "Party mode" button is clicked, the program switches to "party mode". I want the dropdown menu to behave similarly - when the "party mode" option is selected, the program should switch to "party mode".

My logic was that I needed a function that grabbed the value of the dropdown menu, and then an "if" condition would run that pretty much says "If the value is x, x mode should run; else if the value is y, y mode should run", and so on. I added the function to the existing window.onload function so it would run upon the window loading. This didn't work.

Note that the dropdown menu will, in the future, only appear when the screen size is 500px or less. In addition, I still have the buttons on the screen for all sizes, just for testing/debugging purposes. When I'm done and have this figured out, the buttons will have "display = 'none'" and be hidden for the "mobile size".

Anyway, so yeah, the program is still just listening to the buttons, and not the dropdown menu. That leads me to believe that I need to somehow turn "off" the button mode? If that's the case, how do I do that? If that's not the case, what am I supposed to do here? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
const defaultMode = 'default';
const defaultSize = 30;
const defaultColor = '#0b478b';
let currentMode = defaultMode;
let currentSize = defaultSize;
let currentColor = defaultColor;

// Sets the program's current mode
function setCurrentMode(newMode) {
  activeButton(newMode);
  currentMode = newMode;
}

// Sets the grid's size
function setCurrentSize(newSize) {
  currentSize = newSize;
}

// Sets the color of the square (if in default mode)
function setCurrentColor(newColor) {
  currentColor = newColor;
}

// Links the various HTML elements to this script
const sizeValue = document.querySelector('#sizevalue');
const sizeSlider = document.querySelector('#sizeslider');
const colorPicker = document.querySelector('#colorpicker');
const defaultBtn = document.querySelector('#default');
const partyBtn = document.querySelector('#party');
const grayBtn = document.querySelector('#grayscale');
const eraserBtn = document.querySelector('#eraser');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('#clear');
const grid = document.querySelector('#maincontainer');

// DOM manipulations for buttons, color picker, and size slider
colorPicker.onchange = (e) => setCurrentColor(e.target.value);
defaultBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('default');
partyBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('party');
grayBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('gray');
eraserBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('eraser');
clearBtn.onclick = () => reloadGrid();
sizeSlider.onmousemove = (e) => updateSizeValue(e.target.value);
sizeSlider.onchange = (e) => changeSize(e.target.value);

// When the size is changed, we set the grid size, update the size value (text), and reload the grid.
function changeSize(num) {
  setCurrentSize(num);
  updateSizeValue(num);
  reloadGrid();
}

// When we update the size value, the text changes to reflect the value. (It's a square, so the value is always the same for length and width).
function updateSizeValue(num) {
  sizeValue.innerHTML = `${num} x ${num}`;
}

// When we reload the grid (which happens when "Clear grid" is pressed), we ensure that we clear the grid and that the size is still the current size.
function reloadGrid() {
  clearGrid()
  makeGrid(currentSize)
}

// When we clear the grid, it clears the grid.
function clearGrid() {
  grid.innerHTML = ''
}

// Creates the base grid and includes the code that says "when the mouse goes over the squares, draw."
function makeGrid(size) {
  grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  for (i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    let square = document.createElement('div');
    square.addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor);
    grid.appendChild(square);
  }
}

// These are the conditions to set the color of the "pen" (squares)
function changeColor(e) {
  if (currentMode === 'party') {
    const randomR = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const randomG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const randomB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randomR}, ${randomG}, ${randomB})`;
  } else if (currentMode === 'default') {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = currentColor;
  } else if (currentMode === 'gray') {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = calculateGray(e);
  } else if (currentMode === 'eraser') {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
}

// Shading mode code
function calculateGray(e) {
  let clr = returnRGB(e.target.style.backgroundColor);
  if (!clr || clr[1] !== clr[2] || clr[1] !== clr[3]) {
    return `rgb(255, 255, 255)`;
  }
  return clr[1] <= 0 ? `rgb(255, 255, 255)` : `rgb(${clr[1]-25}, ${clr[1]-25}, ${clr[1]-25})`;
}

function returnRGB(num) {
  return num.match(/rgb\(([0-9]*), ([0-9]*), ([0-9]*)\)/);
}

// Changes the button styling to indicate which mode is the active mode
function activeButton(newMode) {
  if (currentMode === 'party') {
    partyBtn.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (currentMode === 'default') {
    defaultBtn.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (currentMode === 'gray') {
    grayBtn.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (currentMode === 'eraser') {
    eraserBtn.classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (newMode === 'party') {
    partyBtn.classList.add('active');
  } else if (newMode === 'default') {
    defaultBtn.classList.add('active');
  } else if (newMode === 'gray') {
    grayBtn.classList.add('active');
  } else if (newMode === 'eraser') {
    eraserBtn.classList.add('active');
  }
}

// Ensures that, when we load the page, we make the grid and activate the correct mode (default).
window.onload = () => {
  makeGrid(defaultSize);
  activeButton(defaultMode);
  dropdownModeThing(document.getElementById('dropdown-mode').value);
}

// Code for the dropdown menu
function dropdownModeThing(val) {
  if (val === 'default') {
    setCurrentMode('default');
  } else if (val === 'party') {
    setCurrentMode('party');
  } else if (val === 'shading') {
    setCurrentMode('gray');
  } else if (val === 'eraser') {
    setCurrentMode('eraser');
  } else if (val === 'clear') {
    reloadGrid();
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #0b478b;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

#maincontainer {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 45vw;
  height: 45vw;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}

.testing {
  padding-top: 100%;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 68%, 0.596);
}

#btncontainer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

a {
  color: #2aa5a1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}

button {
  background-color: #2aa5a1;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #3F86D8;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3F86D8;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0b478b;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
}

#rightside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#sizevalue {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type=range] {
  background-color: white;
  height: 28px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  background: #3F86D8;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000031;
  border: 1px solid #00001E;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #3F86D8;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  background: #3F86D8;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000031;
  border: 1px solid #00001E;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #F3EEED;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3F86D8;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 26px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3F86D8;
  border: 0px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 26px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  margin-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000031;
  border: 1px solid #00001E;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #F3EEED;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3F86D8;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3F86D8;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

#colorpicker {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 100vw;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}

input[type='color']:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

input[type='color']::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type='color']::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}


/* Tooltip container */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  /* To the left of the tooltip */
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0b478b;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #btncontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 10px 5px 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #btncontainer button {
    margin: 0 3px;
    height: 35px;
  }
  #colorpicker {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- CSS spreadsheet -->
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Note that this is set up in various divs so
that we can use Flex to create our wanted layout. -->

  <div id="entirepage">
    <header>
      <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
      <p title="Testing">Select a color or a different mode, then select your size, and get drawing!</p>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="btncontainer">
        <select id="dropdown-mode">
          <option value="default">Default mode</option>
          <option value="party">Party mode</option>
          <option value="shading">Shading</option>
          <option value="eraser">Eraser mode</option>
          <option value="clear">Clear grid</option>
        </select>
        <input type="color" id="colorpicker" value="#0b478b">
        <button id="default">Default mode</button>
        <button id="party">Party mode</button>
        <button id="grayscale">Shading</button>
        <button id="eraser">Eraser mode</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear grid</button>
      </div>
      <div id="rightside">
        <div id="maincontainer">
        </div>
        <label for="sizeslider" id="sizevalue">30 x 30</label>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="30" id="sizeslider">
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Created by Sara Dunlop (<a href="https://www.github.com/Risclover" target="_blank">RiscloverYT</a>)</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript script -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please make this a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: It looks like you just forgot to listen to `onchange` of the dropdown. You only set the mode once using the dropdown, on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, there's an easy way to do that. Add this piece of code into your javascript file and see the magic.

```
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-mode');

dropdown.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  setCurrentMode(e.target.value);
});
```

[*Read more about* `change` *event here.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: Thank you very much! If I could hug you I would. 